# How to create a "U" shape using Snap.svg?

Tags: javascript, svg, polyline, snap.svg

I need to create a reverse U shape using javascript, but I can't figure it out. Somewhat like this polyline shape but curved at the end, using these same points. I have found code examples for complicated animations with curves and stuff but nothing simple.

```
var lsvg = Snap('#svg');

var arrow = lsvg.polyline([6,10, 3,0, 0,10]).attr({stroke: '#000', fill: '#f2f4f3'});
```

[Jsbin](https://jsbin.com/bomeloqafa/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: does that library support bezier curves?

Comment: Have a look at the path command. Or just draw a letter u and scale it 1,-1 to flip it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up following Ian's advice and I used the path command. I actually wanted to use this as a marker for a line, and every time I used the U letter (as text) it appeared deformed, so that's why I couldn't do that.

```
var arrow = lsvg.path("M20,30 Q10,0 0,30").attr({stroke: '#000', fill:"none" });
```

I used three points for this: (20,30) , (10,0) , (0,30).

[Updated Jsbin](https://jsbin.com/bulagohiyu/edit?html,js,output)